# Twin Prime Related Material

Tags: number-theory, reference-request, prime-numbers, twin-primes, goldbachs-conjecture

I'm in a senior seminar class for my undergraduate degree and I am tasked with writing a short, 12 page paper on some subject I have not been taught before.  I chose the twin prime conjecture.  My original plan was to go through the history and proofs surrounding the conjecture; however, the chair of my department told me that proving all of this material would take too much time and learning for such a short paper.  He then suggested that I discuss all of the work that has been done and just prove Viggo Brun's work.  Currently my outline for the paper is as follows:

- Basic Prime proofs
- Introduction to seiving methods and the prime number theorem
- Analysis of Viggo Brun's seiving method and proof
- Proof of Merten's Theorems
- Proof of Brun's theorem
- Analysis of Hardy-Littlewood Conjecture
- Analysis of Goldbach Conjecture
- Analysis of Yitang Zhang's work
- Analysis of the most recent results

I have done some research on these topics, but any nice links to material on any of these subjects would be great.  Any information that I can add to this or any site detailing the connection between the twin prime conjecture, the Goldbach conjecture, or any other conjecture would also be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Yitang Zhang's proof [is at here](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.308.998&rep=rep1&type=pdf)

For sieving method and PNT, [may be this would help](http://www.math.tifr.res.in/~publ/ln/tifr72.pdf)

[Terry Tao's blog](https://terrytao.wordpress.com/tag/goldbach-conjecture/) has many nice articles on Goldbach's conjecture

Comment: Thank you, I have been looking everywhere for Dr. Zhang's proof.  Now I just need to read it, find the important parts, and write about it (:

Answer (score 0):

It's a great outline but a lot for 12 pages.  I suggest you focus on Brun and Zhang's theorems, which are directly related to twin primes, and maybe drop Goldbach, Hardy-Littlewood and Mertens.

Comment: I'm just having trouble thinking of what I would write really.  I need Merten's theorems to prove Brun's, and I can really only discuss Zhang's proof.  Going through the proof would be too much to learn for this paper.